# Find the area of the parallelogram with vertices $K(1, 3, 1), L(1, 6, 3), M(6, 12, 3), N(6, 9, 1)$.

Tags: geometry, vector-spaces

> Find the area of the parallelogram with vertices $K(1, 3, 1), L(1, 6, 3), M(6, 12, 3), N(6, 9, 1)$.

I know that I need to get is an equation of the form (a vector) x (a second vector)

But, how do I decide what the two vectors will be from the points provided (since you cannot really draw it out accurately)?

I know you need to pick one point as the origin of the vector and then find the distance to each point, but which point would be the origin?

Comment: What you wrote is the volume of a parallelepiped, which is a 3-dimension figure. It looks like you indeed have a parallelogram (so you will calculate a 0 volume, which is accurate).

Comment: Oops... I meant the formula a x b for a parallelogram.

Comment: In that case, can you correct the equation, and write it should be? Also show your working so that we can understand what you're doing.

Comment: My problem is finding a potential origin from the points.

Comment: On a parallelogram there are two pairs of parallels opposite sides. So you'll be able to find the pair of parallel vectors.

Answer (score 1):

Given a parallelogram with vertices $A$, $B$, $C$, and $D$, with $A$ diagonally opposite $C$, the vectors you want are $A-B$ and $A-D$.

Comment: But how to find out which vertices given above are A, B, C, and D?

Comment: Of the three vectors $A-B$, $A-C$, $A-D$, one will be the sum of the other two. That's the one to leave out.